# C - Pointers and Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I've been trying to make a write to array method in C, but it does not seem to be returning what I expect.

```
How many numbers would you like to short?: 3
Checking for the i: 0: 1
Setting the number to temp 1
Checking for the i: 1: 2
Setting the number to temp 2
Checking for the i: 2: 3
Setting the number to temp 3
Setting the array2 to *array
0: 6487440
1: 0
2: 6480512

----------------------------------
Proces exited after 1.741 seconds with return value 3
```

And this is the code

```
int array_size;

void getArray(int *array[]);
void printArray(int array[]);

void main() {
    printf("How many numbers would you like to short?: ");
    scanf("%d", &array_size);

    int input[array_size];

    getArray(&input);

    printArray(input);
}

void getArray(int *array[]) {
    int i, temp;
    int array2[array_size];
    for(i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
        printf("Checking for the i: ");
        printf("%d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        printf("Setting the number to temp %d\n", temp);
        array2[i] = temp;
    }

    printf("Setting the array2 to *array\n");
    *array = array2;
}

void printArray(int array[]) {

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
        printf("%d: %d\n", i, array[i]);
    }



}
```

I have also tried using
  scanf("%d", &*array[i]);
but it does not work either.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you intend to do by writing `*array = array2;` ?

Comment: Aren't you seeing warnings when you try to compile this? I get 8 warnings on gcc even when I turn the warnings down to default levels. Fix these first.

Comment: Always show text, never show pictures. (Fixed that for you.)

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: "does not do what I expect" is not a problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing so many things wrong over here. First of all passing an array is not passing array will be simply 
`getArray(&input); --> getArray(input);`.

The 1D-array when passed to a function decays into pointer - making it possible to retain any change made to the array (via pointer) in the called function.

```
void getArray(int *array) {
    int i, temp;
    for(i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
        printf("Checking for the i: ");
        printf("%d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
}
```

This will do whatever you wanted to do. But earlier the assignment was wrong because the automatic variables are deallocated once the function reaches the `}`. So accessing it outside the function scope results in undefined behavior.

---

To give you a more elaborate idea, there are few things (Mostly the error message is being discussed).

If you compiled your code, then you would get some error. Now look at the error message. 
`error: cannot convert 'int (*)[array_size]' to 'int**' for argument '1' to 'void getArray(int**)'`.

`&input` is nothing but `int(*)[array_size]`. It means it is a pointer to an array of `array_size` integers.

From looking at the error message you might think , but where from `int**` coming here in the argument of `getArray()`?

Well you were passing `int* array[]` (you declared that function will receive this as parameter) which means `array` is an array of `int*`-s. Now it decays into the pointer to it's first element.

Now wait, what is the element here? It's a  pointer.

And what is pointer to pointer? Yes, it's `int**`.

Simply there is an error thrown - complaining that it can't convert.

Answer (score 0):

Look at where you have decalred `array2`. As soon as you exit the scope of `getArray()`, the memory for it is **deallocated**. So when you try to access it later you end up with whatever is in memory at that moment.